# how to change the favicon?

Tags: html, jekyll

so i got the picture zip file from https://realfavicongenerator.net/
downloaded the zip, change on this path: 'X:\OneDrive\website\myusername.github.io_site\assets\img\favicons'
the files and replaced all of the files other then the 'brwoserconfig.xml' and 'sitewebmanifest' like its been written in this doc here, https://chirpy.cotes.page/posts/customize-the-favicon/

then i do on my terminal
git add .
git commit -m 'newpicture'
git push origin main

its replacing the picture when the old picture and not chaning to the own i replace on my folder.

is that a bug? it happend tp any one?

i tried to do it few times, but i feel like im missing something?

Comment: The `_site` directory is usually the generated site that isn't under version control, try adding it to `assets` *not* in the `_site` directory.

Comment: hey Benjamin, there is no folder name 'img' in assets, i tried to replace the path's in the HTML code, but when i push it to github it generate those ant pictures again... when i put the pictures in the folder and run it on my local machine the favicon changes, problem happens only when i push it to git hub

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing your directory structure. Is the repository public?

Comment: yes, https://github.com/OshoPython/oshopython.github.io not sure why but on github you cant see the folder '_site'... i have it on my machine and thats where i changed the picture, i tried to create this same folder on the github repository but it didnt help

Comment: That's what I meant: that directory is generated as part of the build process. You have to create the `img/favicons` directory in the existing `assets` directory ([this one](https://github.com/OshoPython/oshopython.github.io/tree/main/assets)). It currently contains a reference to a submodule, if I understand correctly.

Comment: I tried it just now [link](https://github.com/OshoPython/oshopython.github.io/tree/main/assets)... still didn't work. oshopython.github.io as you can see this any is still there =\ EDIT: IT WORKING thanks man, i guess i was to tired [= thanks again~

Answer (score 1):

The `_site` directory is generated by Jekyll during the build process, and usually excluded from version control. Any change you make in there won't be persisted.

You have to create the `img/favicons` directory in the existing top-level `assets` directory instead, and after building, the changes will be reflected in the `_site` directory (and the deployed site).